# what is the best dataType for attribute in database? int or char?

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

I have a table

- transaction (**id**, type, category, amount, comment,...);

what the best dataType for category:

- int: where each number expresses a specific type
- char: where each char expresses a specific type
- insert full name of category

Comment: I would propose an extra table CATEGORIES and your transactions table contains a column being a foreign key to that table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer in the database and in your application framework declare the category attribute as enum to map the integer to a category type described as a string/constant.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pre-defined list of categories and you want to make sure your transaction table uses one of them, use a foreign key to a table containing all those categories.

If you don't want to put any restrictions on the category, use a `varchar` column